# psycopg2でDBサーバに接続出来ない

Tags: python, postgresql

教えてください。psycopg2を使うとエラーが返ります。
ソースコードは

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import psycopg2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    connector = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1",database="pdb",user="pgusr",port=5432, password="pgpsw")
    cursor    = connector.cursor()

    sql = "insert into test_table values('1','python')"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = "insert into test_table values('2','パイソン')"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = "insert into test_table values('3','ぱいそん')"
    cursor.execute(sql)

    connector.commit()

    cursor.close()
    connector.close()
```

で、環境はwindows上のpython2.7.11です。

原因は何なのでしょうか？ダライバーだけをinstallしてもだめですか？
エラー内容は

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test105.py", line 7, in
>   
>       connector = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1",database="pdb",user="pgusr",port=5432,
>   password="pgpsw")   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2__init__.py", line 164, in
>   connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>           Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: `import`は出来ています。エラーはデータベースサーバに接続出来ない、という内容です。エラーに合わせて、若干質問を編集しました。

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQLへの接続に失敗していますので、PostgreSQLにネットワーク接続できるよう環境を整えてください

- サービスが起動していない
- PostgreSQLがネットワーク接続を受け付けるよう設定されていない
- Windows Firewallで接続が許可されていない

Comment: ありがとうございます。ドライバーだけinstallしただけでインポートができるわけないですよね。本来の設定をしないといけませんですよね。ありがとうございます

Comment: お世話になります。
netstat -anp tcpで確認しました。TCP         0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENINGとなっておりますので大丈夫だと思います。ただそのあと
connector = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="pdb",user="psycopg",password="pgpsw")部分とpsycopg2\__init__.py", line 164,を同じに設定しました
NameError: global name 'pdb' is not definedとなりまして"pdb"が定義されていないと出ます。この意味がよくわかりません
よろしくご指導ください